# Android Studio creates empty project folder

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just installed Android Studio on a Windows 7 machine. When I attempt to create a new project of any kind all I get is an empty folder. My Win7 system is up to date. My SDK is populated with most API's. The problem occurs with the most recent versions of Android Studio. Currently at 141.2117773+.

When I try to import any of the sample projects I get a PluginException in GradleLibraryManager (Plugin: Gradle GUI).

I've created a simple project using the command line, but when I try to import the project as an Android Studio or Gradle project I get the same PluginException.

Comment: Can anyone offer advice on troubleshooting this problem? Logs?

Comment: I installed Android Studio on a second, similar machine without issues. Could create and import projects. I then researched and found the IDEA logs in C:\Users\(user)\.AndroidStudio1.3\system\log\idea.log. I compared the logs for both machines and found a lot of Gradle-related problems in the log for the machine on which I could not create projects.

Comment: I then compared the list of plugins between the two machines. On the problem machine I found two Gradle plugins that were not installed on the good machine. I disabled those plugins on the problem machine and can now create and import projects. The plugins were “Gradle Dependencies Helper” and “Gradle GUI”.